# Using IF to count rows and insert with condition

Tags: oracle

The following Oracle SQL does not work. What am I doing wrong? How can I make it work without declaring a variable?

```
IF ((SELECT count(*) FROM IBS_GROUP g WHERE g.NAME = 'gmy-vp1_all') = 0) THEN 
  INSERT INTO IBS_GROUP(ID, GROUP_CONTEXT_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ACTIVE) values (IBS_GROUP_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 6, 'gmy-vp1_all', 'gmy-vp1_all', 'Y')
END IF;
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
IF ((SELECT count(*) FROM IBS_GROUP g WHERE g.NAME = 'gmy-vp1_all') = 0) THEN 
Error report -
Unknown Command

Error starting at line : 2 in command -
INSERT INTO IBS_GROUP(ID, GROUP_CONTEXT_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ACTIVE) values (IBS_GROUP_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 6, 'gmy-vp1_all', 'gmy-vp1_all', 'Y') 
END IF 
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL komutu tam doğru olarak sona ermedi
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: How would declaring a variable help you to achieve your goal?

Comment: Most samples suggest to declare a variable first, then select count(*) into variable and using that variable in the IF statement.

Comment: My the way, I am trying to run this code through SQL Developer. I am OK with declaring a variable if I have to but SQL Developer does not seem to cooperate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO IBS_GROUP(ID, GROUP_CONTEXT_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ACTIVE) 
select IBS_GROUP_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 6, 'gmy-vp1_all', 'gmy-vp1_all', 'Y' 
from dual where (SELECT count(*) FROM IBS_GROUP g WHERE g.NAME = 'gmy-vp1_all') = 0;
```

It's not allowed to use a subquery inside IF statement.

Comment: YES ... YES ... YES ... Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. It was driving me crazy for 4 hours.